# MVC model is not posting the complete list to controller if i delete some random rows from the list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, data-annotations

I have generated textboxes from a list in my model like below:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Invoice", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnComplete = "OnCreateComplete" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Title, new { @placeholder = "Title" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Title)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Description, new { @placeholder = "Description" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Description)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Amount, new { @placeholder = "Amount" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[0].Amount)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Title, new { @placeholder = "Title" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Title)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Description, new { @placeholder = "Description" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Description)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Amount, new { @placeholder = "Amount" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[1].Amount)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Title, new { @placeholder = "Title" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Title)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Description, new { @placeholder = "Description" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Description)</td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Amount, new { @placeholder = "Amount" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceItems[2].Amount)</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

If i submit this, it posts all rows to the controller. But if i delete any random row like 2nd, it only post first row to the controller.

Now i can write a logic to get all valid rows at controller like if i set a skip_rows variable using javascript and in my controller write a loop to read the rows based on form rows & skip_value. 
But instead of this, i am looking for some better approach.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

> If i submit this, it posts all rows to the controller. But if i delete
>   any random row like 2nd, it only post first row to the controller.

Anytime the index chain is broken the model binder loses its magic. So for example you have three items and you remove the last one that leaves you with the following elements:

```
m.InvoiceItems[0]
m.InvoiceItems[1]
// "m.InvoiceItems[2]" was deleted
```

the model binder will be able to pass your InvoiceItems completely - with two items. This next example will not work:

```
m.InvoiceItems[0]
// m.InvoiceItems[1]  was deleted
m.InvoiceItems[2]
```

and so does this (won't work):

```
// m.InvoiceItems[0] was deleted
m.InvoiceItems[1]  
m.InvoiceItems[2]
```

So what can you do? You can flag each row that you deleted with something like `IsDeleted` or `IsRemoved` and make it a property of an `InvoiceItem` and then deal with it in the controller.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing it now. and in this case, all the deleted rows are posted to controller. But I am looking for a approach which can only post valid rows.

Comment: Yeah re-indexing is complex task :P. Is there any alternate and simple way? :)

Comment: You can do an ajax delete instead, but that would be a totally different approach. So each time you remove a row, it's actually deleted, and you don't even have to post the entire form. But like I said, a totally different approach.